# How to edit a property of a certain object from LocalStorage and then put it back in Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Say I have an array of objects:

```
const colors = [
  {
    name: "red",
    label: "red",
    colorHex: "#FF0000",
  },
  {
    name: "blue",
    label: "blue",
    colorHex: "#0000FF",
  },
  {
    name: "yellow",
    label: "yellow",
    colorHex: "#FFFF00",
  },
  {
    name: "green",
    label: "green",
    colorHex: "green",
  },
  {
    name: "purple",
    label: "purple",
    colorHex: "#800080",
  },
  {
    name: "orange",
    label: "orange",
    colorHex: "#ffa500",
  },
  {
    name: "bluegreen",
    label: "blue green",
    colorHex: "#0d98ba",
  },
  {
    name: "blueviolet",
    label: "blue violet",
    colorHex: "#8a2be2",
  },
  {
    name: "yellowgreen",
    label: "yellow green",
    colorHex: "#9acd32",
  },
  {
    name: "redviolet",
    label: "red violet",
    colorHex: "#c71585",
  },
  {
    name: "redorange",
    label: "red orange",
    colorHex: "#ff6600",
  },
  {
    name: "yelloworange",
    label: "yellow orange",
    colorHex: "#ffae42",
  },
];
```

I don't want to look at these objects one by one, or access it by means of indexing. Instead, I just want to take the *object itself* from the array that has the property name `redorange` (by using a for loop or something?) from Local Storage.

Afterwards, I want to edit/change this property to let's say `reddishorange`. And then put it back to Local Storage. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: `colors.find(({ name }) => name === "redorange").name = "reddishorange"`

Comment: For `localStorage`, use `JSON.parse()` when reading and `JSON.stringify()` when writing. I've added another link to the list at the top of your question

Answer (score 1):

```js
var color=colors.find(v=>v.name=="redorange")
color=color || {} //in case not found
color.name="reddishorange"
```

Comment: You could inline the `|| {}` with the first line and make `color` a `const`. Even better, use `?? {}`

Comment: correct, i couldn't even line up all 3 lines, just didn't want to confuse the OP

Comment: I'm sorry @Jew I forgot to include the Local Storage here. Please help.

Comment: vanilla localstorage can only store strings, are you using some library?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it's possible, and not difficult at all.

```
colors.forEach(color => {
  color.name = color.name === "redorange" ? "reddishorange" : color.name
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry @BülentAkgül I forgot to include the Local Storage here. Please help.

Comment: Does local storage mean your hard drive?

Comment: Yes hard drive in my computer.

Comment: Javascript can't change the file. It can read the data, manipulate the data but can save the new data. So you need to use something else, maybe PHP.